# detect if jquery easy ui combobox has focus

Tags: jquery, combobox, jquery-easyui

Let's say I have a jQuery EasyUI combobox like this:

```
<input class="easyui-combobox" id="combobox" data-options="
    valueField: 'label',
    textField: 'value',
    data: [{
        label: 'java',
        value: 'Java'
    },{
        label: 'perl',
        value: 'Perl'
    },{
        label: 'ruby',
        value: 'Ruby'
}]" />
```

How do I dectect when the combobox has focus and then perform some action accordingly?

I tried stuff like:

```
$('#combobox').focus(function(){
    alert('FOCUS');
});
```

and

```
var combobox_panel = $('#combobox').combobox('panel');

combobox_panel.focus(function(){
    alert('FOCUS');
});
```

But none of those work. Any idea please?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried.. `$(#coombobox1).bind("focus", function () {
    });`

Comment: I don't wanna bind focus, I wanna detect if the element has focus

Comment: When/where do you want to do it ?

Comment: I wanna know it when the user makes a selection from the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the original input is destroyed and replaced by a new "fake" input to make it pretty. You can try looking for `combo-text validatebox-text` classes together on an element and bind to that.

```
$('.combo-text.validatebox-text').on('focus', function() {
    alert('here'); // warning, for some reason I keep alerting.
});
```

It's not perfect but it's a start. inspect the input element in Chrome or FF and you will see how the library builds the new input.

### edit

After reading your comments you really only need to know when the user has selected a value.

```
$('.combobox-item').on('click', function() {
    alert(this.textContent);
});
```